# Using a Facebook Pixel, how does one trigger the activated app event using the JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do you get a FB pixel to fire when an app is installed or activated using the javascript SDK?

Based on the FB documentation, we are using:

```
FB.AppEvents.activateApp();
```

We have verified that the SDK is loaded, and the `FB.AppEvents` object and `activateApp` function exist.

We are able to log events using:

```
fbq('track','xxx');
```

When we use the helper tool provided by FB to test the pixel:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/

it indicates that the app is setup, but that 'no installs were recorded in the past 7 days', even though we know that there have been installs, and they should have fired the call above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell, it's only possible to do this for iOS or Android apps using the native SDK or one of the cordova plugins (eg currently cordova-plugin-facebook4).  If someone knows how to do this with the JS SDK, please post.